# Moment get today to specific format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the date today in moment, in the following format:
`2018-05-03 07:30:00+03`

I tried the following but it doesn't format properly,

```js
const today = moment(moment().toDate()).format('YYYY MM DD HH:mm');
console.log(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

but i get `2019 07 29 12:47`, so i don't get the timezone, neither the `-` between dates.

Suggestions?

Comment: Just `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ');`

Comment: That's what i'm doing atm

Comment: Not duplicate! I need the timezone too, and your reply is also wrong :P

Comment: No need to use `moment(moment().toDate())`, you can simply use `moment()`. You can use `Z` and `ZZ` to [display](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) timezone offset but the output will always include minutes (since not all offsets end has 0 minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hyphens wherever needed and I think `Z` will help you with timezone:

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or `ZZ` to remove the hyphen in timezone:

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your formatting string, this should get you what you need:

```js
const today = moment(moment().toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ');
console.log(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

const today = moment(moment().toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ');